# Retornando número semana do mês

Tags: delphi, data

No mês de Janeiro deste ano (2018) eu tenho 5 semanas no mesmo, sendo elas:

**1 semana:** 1 a 7;

**2 semana:** 8 a 14;

**3 semana:** 15 a 21;

**4 semana:** 22 a 28 e

**5 semana:** 29 a 31 (ou para outros de 29 a 04 de Fevereiro).

Ao utilizar a função `WeekOfTheYear`a aplicação me retorna o dia `29` como sendo semana 1, o que não é verdade.

Alguma solução para este problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talvez isso possa te ajudar:

```
weekNum: Integer; 
weekNum:=(StrToInt(FormatDateTime('dd',Date)) - 1) div 7 + 1 ;
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!